# Technically, is a strictly monotonic increasing an nondecreasing sequence of sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am learning this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit), which uses `sequence of sets` in the definition

> Suppose that ${\displaystyle \{A_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty }}$ is a sequence
>   of sets. The two equivalent definitions are as follows.
>
> Using union and intersection, define
>
> $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n = \bigcup_{n \ge 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$
>
> ...
>
> The sequence ${A_n}$ is said to be nondecreasing if each $A_n ⊂
> A_{n+1}$

to understand this concept easily, I would like to introduce some concrete examples.

the simplest example of a (monotonic increasing) sequence I can imagine is the Natural number $(0, 1, 2, …)$

so, I am trying to construct an nondecreasing sequence of sets based on that.

this sequence $(\{0\}, \{0, 1\}, ..., \{0, 1, 2, …\})$ is a strictly monotonic increasing sequence of sets.

is this an nondecreasing sequence of sets? in another word, is a strictly monotonic increasing sequence of sets an nondecreasing sequence of sets?

Comment: Technically, is $0\leq 1$?

Comment: Usually, we call "non decreasing" a sequence with $\le$ and "strictly increasing" one with $<$.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to be "technically" about it -- being strictly increasing is a perfectly good way for a sequence to be non-decreasing.

The difference between the concepts is that a "non-decreasing" sequence is *allowed to* have $A_{n+1}=A_n$ sometimes (or even $A_{n+1}=A_n$ *always*). But it doesn't *have* to do that.

---

Usually saying that a sequence of sets is "nondecreasing" will be understood to mean that $A_{n+1}\supseteq A_n$ for all $n$. In other words, it is not enough that $\neg(A_{n+1}\subsetneq A_n)$, so $\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots$ will not count as "nondecreasing".

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Most of which is easy to understand for me except the last example. To be clear, your example $\{0\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\ldots$ is different to mine, right? So, Mine is an nondecreasing sequence of sets and yours is not, right?

Comment: @yaojp: correct.

Comment: Does $\neg(A_{n+1}\subsetneq A_n)$ mean a complement of a sequence, if yes, what is the universe where the sequence and its complement live.

Comment: It just means that $A_{n+1}\subsetneq A_n$ is not true about the sequence, @yaojp.